# HttpCookie.hasExpired() do not work properly at pre Nougat(24)

Tags: android, cookies, kotlin

This code simply logs cookie list and boolean which cookie has expired every 1 seconds.

I run this source code using AVD emulator API 23.
And then, `HttpCookie.hasExpired()` returns only `false`.
However, It was okay when I run the code in Nougat(24~25) and Oreo.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val TAG = this.javaClass.name

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val cookieStore = CookieManager().cookieStore
        val testCookie = HttpCookie("test", "value")
            .also { it.maxAge = 5 }

        cookieStore.add(URI.create("http://localhost"), testCookie)

        Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                Log.i(TAG, "cookies = ${cookieStore.cookies}, expired = ${testCookie.hasExpired()}")
            }
        }, 0, 1000)
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?
It works well on non-Android using following code.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val cookieStore = CookieManager().cookieStore
    val testCookie = HttpCookie("test", "value")
        .also { it.maxAge = 5 }

    cookieStore.add(URI.create("http://localhost"), testCookie)

    Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(object : TimerTask() {
        override fun run() {
            println("${Date()} | cookies = ${cookieStore.cookies}, expired = ${testCookie.hasExpired()}")
        }
    }, 0, 1000)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we compare between the [source code of HttpCookie in API 23](https://github.com/AndroidSDKSources/android-sdk-sources-for-api-level-23/blob/master/java/net/HttpCookie.java) and the [source code of HttpCookie in API 24](https://github.com/AndroidSDKSources/android-sdk-sources-for-api-level-24/blob/master/java/net/HttpCookie.java) we could see significant behaviour difference in the `hasExpired()` method, this is probably the cause of that issue.